# Find the Vagrantfile folder

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to tweak my Vagrantfile so it automatically creates a folder in the project root if it's missing. Creating the folder is no problem, but I'm having trouble finding out *where* to create that folder.

I was able to figure out that this information is available on a `Vagrant::Environment` object as `cwd`, but I can't figure out how to get the current instance from inside my Vagrantfile. The documentation for Vagrant seems to be a bit sparse.

Edit:

My question is not about how to use Puppet. I'm writing some code *inside* the Vagrantfile. I want to know how to get the current instance of `Vagrant::Environment`.

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I mentioned the method I want to call, I just don't know how to get the current instance of the class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To find the Vagrantfile directory try this in the Vagrantfile:

```rb
vagrant_root = File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: If in a subdir, it seems to return that path instead of the `Vagrantfile` path :( I wonder if there is a way to consistently get the `Vagrantfile` path

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this `Vagrant::Environment` object is... it seems to be undocumented...

If I wanted to make a new folder in the same directory as my `Vagrantfile` I would just use the shell provisioner:

```
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "mkdir -p /vagrant/test_folder;"
```

If you want the folder that contains the `Vagrantfile` on your host machine then try putting this in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
  puts Dir.pwd
```

That should print the directory... so you can then try doing things with that variable.

Comment: Dir.pwd will give the vagrant root when in the root dir, but if in a subdir, it will give that.

Comment: @patcon, same with the accepted answer: `File.dirname(__FILE__)` ... surely there is some way to reliably get the Vagrantfile path

Answer (score -1):

By default, root directory is `/home/vagrant`

Here' an example to create `new_folder` using `vagrant` user

```
  exec { 'create folder':
    cwd     => '/home/vagrant',
    user    => 'vagrant',
    command => 'mkdir new_folder',
    unless  => "/usr/bin/test -d /home/vagrant/new_folder",
  }
```

Comment: My question was not about puppet.

Comment: `/home/vagrant` is on the VM, and it's not (normally) where you'd find the Vagrantfile.  I think the OP is asking about the directory that the Vagrantfile is in ***on the host machine***, since its location on the VM is only there by virtue of sharing/syncing the directory.